# Rangy injection module issue

Tags: serialization, inject, rangy

I'm trying to inject the rangy javascript core and serializer code base (https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) into an html page. However when I inject it, the rangy object isn't created properly. The modules are added at rangy.modules.* however the functions created within the module are not added to the rangy object. Also the modules all have the following variables 'initialized' and 'supported' as false. Has anyone been able to inject the Rangy code base into their web page properly or can provide any assistance?

To inject - open up Chrome javascript console and insert code as minified (very important or it will not work - http://jscompress.com/):

javascript: *insert code here*

Comment: Have you tried calling `rangy.init()`?

Comment: I did not realize it had an init function. This worked, thanks a million. If you want to post this as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `rangy.init()` to initialize Rangy after the page has loaded.